# como hago para calcular la nota mas alta?

Tags: java

```
package ronald;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NotasAlumnos {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner examen = new Scanner(System.in);
  double notaMayor= -1;
  double notaAlumno1;
  System.out.println("     LISTADO DE NOTAS    ");
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Primer Alumno= ");

  notaAlumno1 = examen.nextDouble();

  System.out.println("nota= " + notaAlumno1);
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Segundo Alumno");
  notaAlumno1 = examen.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("nota= " + notaAlumno1);

  double alumno2;
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Segundo Alumno");
  alumno2 = examen.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("nota= " + alumno2);

  double alumno3;
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Tercer Alumno");
  alumno3 = examen.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("nota= " + alumno3);

  double alumno4;
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Cuarto Alumno");
  alumno4 = examen.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("nota= " + alumno4);

  double alumno5;
  System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Quinto Alumno");
  alumno5 = examen.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("nota= " + alumno5);

  double notaMedia = (notaAlumno1 + alumno2 + alumno3 + alumno4 + alumno5) / 5;
  System.out.println("la media es  = " + notaMedia);

  if (notaAlumno1 < notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 1 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
  } else if (notaAlumno1 > notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 1 esta por encima de la nota media ");
  }

  if (alumno2 < notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 2 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
  } else if (alumno2 > notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 2 esta por encima de la nota media ");
  }

  if (alumno3 < notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 3 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
  } else if (alumno3 > notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 3 esta por encima de la nota media ");
  }
  if (alumno4 < notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 4 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
  } else if (alumno4 > notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 4 esta por encima de la nota media");
  }
  if (alumno5 < notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 5 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
  } else if (alumno5 > notaMedia) {
    System.out.println("alumno 5 esta por encima de la nota media");//***queda calcular nota mayor****-
  }

}
}
```

como hago para calcular nota mayor, que me sirva para este código que realice

Answer (score 1):

Es este caso Utiliza un metodo de ordenamiento para acomodar la puntuacion mas alta con un array, despues estos datos se reorganizaran de mayor a menor o menor a mayor, solo basta con reintegrear el primer array en donde estara la nota mas alta.

```
for (p = 1; p < notaMayor.length; p++) {
        aux = notaMayor[p];
        j = p - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (aux > notaMayor[j])) {

            notaMayor[j + 1] = notaMayor[j];
            j--;
        }
        notaMayor[j + 1] = aux;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Nota Mas Alta : " + notaMayor[0]);
```

Con lo anterior mostrado se genera el metodo de inserccion directa, donde con un ciclo for recorremos el largo del array, con esto despues se restaria una posicion para ir moviendo nuestra posicion a una anterior de la otra y comparar, al final quedaria:

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner examen = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[] notaMayor = new double[5];
    double notaAlumno1;
    int p, j;
    double aux;
    System.out.println("     LISTADO DE NOTAS    ");
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Primer Alumno= ");

    notaAlumno1 = examen.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("nota= " + notaAlumno1);
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Segundo Alumno");
    notaAlumno1 = examen.nextDouble();
    notaMayor[0] = notaAlumno1;
    System.out.println("nota= " + notaAlumno1);

    double alumno2;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Segundo Alumno");
    alumno2 = examen.nextDouble();
    notaMayor[1] = alumno2;
    System.out.println("nota= " + alumno2);

    double alumno3;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Tercer Alumno");
    alumno3 = examen.nextDouble();
     notaMayor[2] = alumno3;
    System.out.println("nota= " + alumno3);

    double alumno4;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Cuarto Alumno");
    alumno4 = examen.nextDouble();
    notaMayor[3] = alumno4;
    System.out.println("nota= " + alumno4);

    double alumno5;
    System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Quinto Alumno");
    alumno5 = examen.nextDouble();
    notaMayor[4] = alumno5;
    System.out.println("nota= " + alumno5);

    double notaMedia = (notaAlumno1 + alumno2 + alumno3 + alumno4 + alumno5) / 5;
    System.out.println("la media es  = " + notaMedia);

    
    
   
    
    

    if (notaAlumno1 < notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 1 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
    } else if (notaAlumno1 > notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 1 esta por encima de la nota media ");
    }

    if (alumno2 < notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 2 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
    } else if (alumno2 > notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 2 esta por encima de la nota media ");
    }

    if (alumno3 < notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 3 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
    } else if (alumno3 > notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 3 esta por encima de la nota media ");
    }
    if (alumno4 < notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 4 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
    } else if (alumno4 > notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 4 esta por encima de la nota media");
    }
    if (alumno5 < notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 5 esta por debajo de la nota media ");
    } else if (alumno5 > notaMedia) {
        System.out.println("alumno 5 esta por encima de la nota media");


    }

    for (p = 1; p < notaMayor.length; p++) {
        aux = notaMayor[p];
        j = p - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (aux > notaMayor[j])) {

            notaMayor[j + 1] = notaMayor[j];
            j--;
        }
        notaMayor[j + 1] = aux;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Nota Mas Alta : " + notaMayor[0]);
    
}}
```

Espero te sirva!

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías almacenar las notas en un arreglo

```
  double[]array=new double[5];
  System.out.println("     LISTADO DE NOTAS    ");
  for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
     System.out.println("Ingrese Nota del Alumno #"+(i+1));
     array[i]=examen.nextDouble();  
  }
```

y posteriormente recorrerlo para hallar el mayor,la evaluación seria si la `notaMayor` es menor a la primera nota almacenada en el `array` la `notaMayor` sera igual a esa nota..y asi sucesivamente tomando la `notaMayor` el valor del mayor numero dentro del array

```
int indiceDeAlumnoConMayorNota=0;
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++ ) {
        if(notaMayor<array[i]){
           notaMayor=array[i];
           indiceDeAlumnoConMayorNota=(i+1);
        }
     }

System.out.println("El alumno #"+indiceDeAlumnoConMayorNota+" con nota "+notaMayor+"es el que tiene la nota mas alta");
```

Comment: +1. Buena respuesta... como siempre. No se quien pudo haberte votado negativo, pero ojalá sea capaz mínino de dejar un comentario diciendo por qué.

Comment: muchas gracias!!